# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter deprecated in my project

Tags: spring-boot, websecurity

I have implemented a method security config and extended with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but since it was deprecated, i made few changed in my original code and implemented it without deprecation. But still shows multiple errors in my stack trace. Can someone look into this code, where i'm going wrong.

```
*Original Code With Deprecation:*


package com.chay.security.service.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig{
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

//  AUTHENTICATION
    
    @Override
    protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
       
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

//  AUTHORIZATION
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/join").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers("/user/**", "/post/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
    

}

*Code Without Deprecation:*


package com.chay.security.service.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

//  AUTHENTICATION
    
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return null;
    }
    
        
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

//  AUTHORIZATION

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/join").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**")
                .authenticated().and().httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
    
    

}
```